# Nested Portlet with different contents based on producId

Tags: liferay, portlet

Need your help guys, here is my scenario. I have my product-detail page to show details of all of my products, This detail- page has this standard liferay NestedPortlet. 
Now what i want is that based on producId , show a different NestedPortlet contents. This NestedPortlet can have different other portlets/webcontents(Even layouts) depending productId.

I would appreciate if you could point me in right direction.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is that there should be communication between two portlets. That is based on an event fired from one portlet the contents of another portlet should get changed. If that is the case you do not need even nested portlets.

You can use [Inter Portlet Communication (IPC)](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication?_36_pageResourcePrimKey=6629472) to cater your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the product id in the request object, you can develop a custom layout template, which will access the product id in the layout.tpl, and render different portlet columns basedon that product id, using the $processor.processColumn("columnid") available in layout templates